# Асинхронность запросов к базе данных MYSQL в телеграм боте

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, telegram, асинхронность, aiogram

Всем привет!

Пишу небольшого телеграм бота, который ищет данные отправленные в бота на совпадения в базе данных mysql. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Если бота используют более 1 человека, то запросы обрабатываются по очереди и пока первому не придёт результат второй будет ждать.
Вопрос: Как решить данную проблему? Может быть вы мне подскажите или есть какие-либо уроки/гайды на этот счёт(желательно на ру языке.)

p.s. Опыт в создании ботов, да и в принципе в создании кода у меня чуть больше чем неделя :) Поэтому многие вещи для меня не понятны, но я решил начать сразу с практики попутно осваивая теорию для моих задач в боте.

Для создания бота используется библиотека aiogram.

```html
import logging
import config
import importlib
import datetime

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton,InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

import sys
importlib.reload(sys)

class Test(StatesGroup):
    Q1 = State()
    Q2 = State()

# log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# bot init
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# DB CONNECT
try:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="",
      user="",
      passwd="",
      port="",
      database=""
    )
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Что-то не так с вашим именем пользователя или паролем")
    sys.exit()
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("База данных не существует")
    sys.exit()
  else:
    print(err)
    sys.exit()

cursor = db.cursor()

# Создание базы ,если нет.
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS a0549853_td_bd")

# Создание таблицы, если нет.
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_info (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, \
sub INT, lang VARCHAR(255), userid INT, login VARCHAR(255), until TEXT)")
db.commit()
# /DB CONNECT

# Поиск phone по userid
@dp.message_handler(commands="userid")
async def handle_text (message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите телеграм id пользователя для поиска в базе:")
    await Test.Q2.set()

    @dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], state=Test.Q2)
    async def handle_text(message):
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ожидайте пару секунд. Идёт поиск...')
        cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(
            """
            SELECT phone
            FROM tg_table
            WHERE userid = %s
            """,
            (message.text,)
        )
        db.commit()

        data = cursor.fetchone()

        if data is None:
                await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Данные не найдены. Попробуй /login')
                await state.finish()
        else:
            cursor.execute("""SELECT sub FROM user_info WHERE userid = %s """, (message.from_user.id,))
            db.commit()
            check_sub = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            if check_sub == 0:
                await message.answer("Данные есть в базе. Чтобы посмотреть оформите подписку!")
                await state.finish()
            else:
                if check_sub == 1:
                    for x in data:
                        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Телефон: {x}\n")
                        await state.finish()

# run long-polling
if __name__ == '__main__':
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы используете синхронный коннектор (драйвер) к mysql.

Синхронный драйвер при каждом запросе полностью блокирует обработку.

Нужно использовать асинхронный драйвер https://pypi.org/project/aiomysql/ или https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-async-dd/

В случае с `aiomysql` код практически не изменится. Нужно только изменить то, как создается connection и, так как все методы в API такие же, то ко всем вызовам к БД добавить `await`:

```
cursor = await db.cursor()
await cursor.execute(...)
```

Для `mysql-connector-async-dd` изменения будут чуть больше. Нужно будет всю работу с БД вынести в отдельную функцию. Но это в любом случае хорошо сделать, чтоб разделить обязанности. Приблизительно так:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def query_db_for_user(user_id):
    cursor = yield from db.cursor(buffered=True)
    yield from cursor.execute(
            """
            SELECT phone
            FROM tg_table
            WHERE userid = %s
            """,
            (user_id,)
        )
    
    data = yield from cursor.fetchone()
    return data

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], state=Test.Q2)
async def handle_text(message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ожидайте пару секунд. Идёт поиск...')
    user = await query_db_for_user(message.text)
    if user:
        # пользователь существует
    else:
        # пользователя нет
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Под эти новые драйвера мне придётся полностью переписывать код?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Иду пробовать.

Comment: `yield from` можно переписать как `await`, а декоратор как async - и вы получите не такой уж кардинально другой код)